# Time don't move forward , it stays on the same time

Tags: java

So I ran a code with a variable named `lasttime` containing currenttimemilis method and is outside of while condition ,then i print it inside of while condition, surprisingly the `lasttime` variable stay the same, Why the Lasttime variable doesn't change even though time is changing. I have been looking for this in google but I don't know the keyword
this is the code

```
 void GameStart(){
    long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(playing == true) {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(lastTime);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You only assign to lastTime once. Why would you expect it to change?

Comment: Because you are setting `lastTime` only once (before the loop) and never reassign it. Why do you think, the value chanegs? Did you want to have `lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis()` inside your loop?

Answer (score 2):

```
 void GameStart(){
    long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(playing == true) {
        lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(lastTime);
    }
    
}
```

You assigned it once before the while loop. It will get initialized with that time. You have to reassign current time again to update it like above.

Comment: i just want to make things clear , are you saying that the variabel is filled with the currenttime of when the variable is executed , not the currenttime of right now ?

Comment: The variable is filled with a _value_, It just happens to be the timestamp (the result of calling `System.currentTimeMillis()`). And yes, it is only assigned once!

Comment: Right. When variable assignment is executed, that time will be assigned.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static Timestamp getCurrentTime() {
        Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
        return ts;
    }
```